# spyder debugging stops at the first line

Tags: debugging, spyder, ipdb

this is my code

```
a= 1+10
b =1+20
c=1+5
print(a)
print ('hello')
```

I set breakpoints on line 3 and line 5. However, when i run Debug (Ctrl + F5) in a Spyder Console, it got stuck as shown below even after I updated my Spyder:

```
----> 1 a= 1+10
      2 b =1+20
      3 c=1+5
      4 print(a)
      5 print ('hello')

ipdb>
```

Comment: in my other computer, the spyder debugging for the above codes will work nicely. So I am pretty sure it's caused by this specific computer/python/spyder. Just not sure how to resolve this without reinstalling the whole anaconda...

Comment: We have the same issue. I solved it by the method from here. [Spyder Debugger hangs (not debugging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71117153/spyder-debugger-hangs-not-debugging?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)