# Updating Spyder in Anaconda to 5.2.2

Tags: python, debugging, anaconda, spyder

I feel like I'm going absolutely insane as I can't find any information on this anywhere... Is there anyway to update Spyder in Anaconda Navigator to version 5.2.2? The navigator shows that the highest possible version for Spyder is 5.1.5:

[image: This shows the versions available for Spyder in Anaconda]

I particularly want to update to 5.2.2 because the debugger in 5.1.5 is broken, and it seems the only correct way to fix it is to update to 5.2.2. See [Link to stackoverflow stating that one needs to update to 5.2.2 to fix the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71117153/spyder-debugger-hangs-not-debugging?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

I've tried:

```
conda install spyder==5.2.2
```

but it just says "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - spyder==5.2.2"

I've also tried:

```
pip install spyder==5.2.2
```

But get the error "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\##\Anaconda3\envs\spyder\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions."

Also trying,

```
pip install spyder==5.2.2 --user
```

The command does seem to run to completion without error, but the IDE doesn't seem to have updated as it still says it's 5.1.5 and it also says some things about a warning of missing dependencies (and the debugger still doesn't work).

Any suggestions?

Comment: switched from `spyder` to `vs code` a while back for reasons like this and more...

Comment: Never use pip to update conda packages

Answer (score 2):

Spyder 5.2.2 is only available for the moment through the conda-forge channel. To install it I recommend you to create a new env using only conda-forge packages. You can do that by running from an Anaconda prompt something like the following:

```
conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge python=3.9 spyder=5.2.2
```

To check what is the latest version available in the different channels you can go to https://anaconda.org/search?q=spyder

**Edit:** Currently Spyder 5.2.2 is available from the default anaconda channel. However, the latest Spyder release currently is 5.3.2. Just in case, the conda command to get the latest Spyder version installed in a new env with Python 3.9 looks something like:

```
conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge python=3.9 spyder
```

Comment: You might want to add information on how to find this kind of information in the future, e.g. by [searching on anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=spyder)

Answer (score 1):

I have run the following in command prompt window. It has helped

conda remove spyder

conda remove python-language-server

conda update anaconda

conda install spyder=5.2.2